# How to get key-value of XML in hashmap using java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, w3c

I am facing a issue where I am not able to get the value in my hashmap as per the key of the XML while I am getting the parent key

Code I am using:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

            try {
        String XML="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\r\n" + 
                "<sj0:Msg>\r\n" + 
                "   xmlns:sj0=\"http://fakesite.org/\"\r\n" + 
                "   xmlns:sj1=\"http://fakesite.org/ind\"\r\n" + 
                "   <sj0:Hdr>\r\n" + 
                "       <sj2:Option>CreateTxn</sj2:Option>\r\n" + 
                "       <sj2:ID>172246</sj2:ID>\r\n" + 
                "       <sj2:CountryCode>CR</sj2:CountryCode>\r\n" + 
                "   </sj0:Hdr>\r\n" + 
                "   <sj0:ReqDet>\r\n" + 
                "       <sj0:MReq>\r\n" + 
                "           <sj0:qCore>\r\n" + 
                "               <sj1:Reference>12345678</sj1:Reference>\r\n" + 
                "               <sj1:BrnCode>CLM</sj1:BrnCode>\r\n" + 
                "               <sj1:Source>M1T722</sj1:Source>\r\n" + 
                "               <sj1:TxnLegCount>2</sj1:TxnLegCount>\r\n" + 
                "           </sj0:qCore>\r\n" + 
                "       </sj0:MReq>\r\n" + 
                "       <sj0:LReq>\r\n" + 
                "           <sj0:RCore>\r\n" + 
                "               <sj1:Amt>19.28</sj1:Amt>\r\n" + 
                "               <sj1:Dt>2019-09-04</sj1:Dt>\r\n" + 
                "               <sj1:Date>2019-06-27</sj1:Date>\r\n" + 
                "           </sj0:RCore>\r\n" + 
                "       </sj0:LReq>\r\n" + 
                "       <sj0:LReq>\r\n" + 
                "           <sj0:RCore>\r\n" + 
                "               <sj1:Ind>DC</sj1:Ind>\r\n" + 
                "               <sj1:Currency>US</sj1:Currency>\r\n" + 
                "               <sj1:LAmt>20.28</sj1:LAmt>\r\n" + 
                "           </sj0:RCore>\r\n" + 
                "       </sj0:LReq>\r\n" + 
                "   </sj0:ReqDet>\r\n" + 
                "</sj0:Msg>";


            String XString = XML;
            System.out.println(XML);
            HashMap<String, String> values = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Document xml = convertStringToDocument(XString);

            Node user = xml.getFirstChild();

            NodeList childs = user.getChildNodes();

            Node child;
            for (int i = 0; i < childs.getLength(); i++) {
                child = childs.item(i);
                System.out.println(child.getNodeName());
                System.out.println(child.getNodeType());
                System.out.println(child.getUserData("Source"));
                System.out.println(child.getTextContent());
                values.put(child.getNodeName(), child.getTextContent());
            }

            System.out.println("Source name");
            System.out.println(values.toString());
            System.out.println(values.get("Source"));

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}

     private static Document convertStringToDocument(String xmlStr) {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder;
        try {
            builder  = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlStr.getBytes("UTF-8"))));


            return doc;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Output:

> {sj0:ReqDet=
>
> ```
>           12345678
>           CLM
>           M1T722
>           2
>
>
>
>
>           19.28
>           2019-09-04
>           2019-06-27
>
>
>
>
>           DC
>           US
>           20.28
>
>       , #text= , sj0:Hdr=         CreateTxn       172246      CR  }
> ```

I need to add Source in haspmap key not ReqDet.
**I am facing issue to traverse through the XML.**
Any idea where I am going wrong and also please explain how I can get the value of other keys-value i.e. Ind key of RCore parent key.

I am fine with any other approach or library to do achieve this task if this library have issue

Comment: @MihaiC - I have refer your answer in another post.. can you please help me on same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below line of code having `"*"` which means it will select all nodes/key-values from the XML

```
NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("*");
```

Below is the full code works for me:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String XML="YOUR XML";

    HashMap<String, String> values =convertStringToDocument(XML);
    System.out.println("values = "+values.get("sj1:Source"));
}

public static HashMap<String, String> convertStringToDocument(String xmlStr) {
    HashMap<String, String> values = new HashMap<String, String>();
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder;
    try {
        builder  = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        EntityResolver resolver = new EntityResolver() {
            public InputSource resolveEntity(String publicId, String systemId) {
                String empty = "";
                ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(empty.getBytes());
                System.out.println("resolveEntity:" + publicId + "|" + systemId);
                return new InputSource(bais);
            }
        };
        builder.setEntityResolver(resolver);
        Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlStr.getBytes("UTF-8"))));
        NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("*");
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node node = nodeList.item(i);
            if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                values.put(node.getNodeName(), node.getTextContent());
            }
        }

        return values;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```